# How to get maximum date from two tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have joined two tables based on  **Fkey** parent  and displayed the first tables using group  by i have grouped the **Fkey** and found the minimum date as min date in table 1  i want to check table 2 where these minimum date matches or equal means want to display  and  also same for maximum date  .

```
SELECT   a.fld_fkey_field,    
Date_format(Min(Str_to_date(a.fld_field_8,'%m/%d/%y')),'%m/%d/%y') AS min_date, 
     b.fld_field_6,     
date_format(max(str_to_date(a.fld_field_9',%m/%d/%y')),'%m/%d/%y') AS max_date, 
     b.fld_field_7 
FROM     tbl_section_23 a 
JOIN     tbl_section_21 b 
ON       a.fkey_parent=b.fkey_parent 
GROUP BY a.fld_fkey_field
```

Comment: use MAX(DateColumn)

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS when you're question is only related to one. Neither `STR_TO_DATE` or `Date_Format` are T-SQL functions, so I have assumed MySQL. I also strongly suggest adding some formatting to your code; that is very fard to read with the line break =s in random places. I suspect that the code `(a.Fld_Field_9',%m/%d/%y')` is malformed, as you have the comma (`,`) in the literal string.

Comment: Also, although this is a SQL Server article, the point still applies: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: seems it is not date column,but string (in american form - worst for indexing). One of database antipattern. Suggest change db design

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?